# Error detected while processing function <SNR>68_NetrwOpenFile when creating a new file with %

Tags: neovim

I get this error when I try to create a new file in netrw. It looks like its coming from netrw but I also get a similar error when I go up the directory tree with vim-vinegar

`Error detected while processing function <SNR>68_NetrwOpenFile BufEnter autocommands for "*" ... function AutoPairsTryInit`

I am also am curious how I would diagnose this myself?

Comment: It seems to me that the error occur in the `AutoPairsTryInit`. This function is present in some auto-pairs plugin like the [auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) plugin. Do you confirm that you have that plugin installed?

Comment: Yeah I have that plugin. I disabled it and i will test out if the issue continues

Comment: The problem could be related to the file you load. Maybe could tell us more about it.